# Database design with two related tables

Tags: sql, database-design

I have two tables: one contains appointment data (time, contact...) and another contains notes (strings). Some appointments have notes and some notes are related to appointments but not all appointments have notes and not all notes are related to an appointment. What's going to be better?

```
a) In the appointments table, add a field that contains a noteID
b) In the notes table, add a field that contains an appointmentID
c) Do both
```

How should I decide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do neither.

Use an associative join table.

You have three tables.

- Notes, with a note ID
- Appointments, with an Appointment ID
- Associations with a Note ID and an Appointment ID.

Comment: This is the best version of the right answer: Every table gets a single autonumber primary key ID field.

Comment: +1 - And this method allows for the easiest multiple notes per appt or appts per note!

Answer (score 1):

D) Neither.

Add a third table called Appointment_Notes.  The two columns of this table would be AppointmentID and NoteID (or whatever your primary keys for those table are called).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple notes that relate to one appointment, or for that matter multiple appointments that relate to one note, you'd need to make some type of connection table that connects the appointments and note tables together based on a primary key.  That way, those notes that aren't related to an appointment can remain independent, but there is no limit to the connections of notes to appointments, or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

d) Create a new table to represent the intersection of appointments and notes. The new table consists of the primary key from each table, referenced as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You could have another table, which connects the two, and is made up of apptID and noteID. This would eliminate the need for null values in the foreign-key of your parent table.

Answer (score 0):

How you are describing your application, it's just a coincidence that some appointments have notes and some notes have appointments.

I'd create a third `appointment_notes` (appointment_id, note_id) table that happen to be the association of primary keys of both previously mentioned tables.